# How to set up an SSTP Server

Tags: vpn

Is there a way to set up a linux based, preferably ubuntu, SSTP server? I know there is a SSTP client available on sourceforge, but I can't find a server.

To be clear: I do NOT want openVPN, I want SSTP.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, there is a Linux (and Windows/Mac) based SSTP (and lot more) VPN Server. It is called SoftEther VPN (http://www.softether.org). I used it on Ubuntu 13.04 release.  Best of off, it is free. Granted, there are couple of limitations with the free version (for example, cannot use external authentication, client certificates etc.)

In general, it seems to work fine. It is quite easy to install, use and manage. Has decently good documentation. Has quite a few options.  It does serve my SSTP server needs.

Comment: This SoftEther VPN seem to me a very interesting new project. It seem to do SSTP among the others. I read the site and they say it is freeware and is planned to be open-source software (GNU General Public License) in the middle of 2013. On paper there are many intresting features but I have not tried it so perhaps other feedbacks are needed.

Comment: It's open source since January 4, 2014. So most probably the restrictions don't apply anymore (haven't checked that).

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**
Shortly after this answer was written, the University of Tsukuba released their first release of [SoftEther](https://www.softether.org/), which runs on Linux and does provide a Microsoft-compatible SSTP server implementation.

**ORIGINAL**
There is no SSTP server software for Linux currently available. There is an SSTP client available for Linux and SSTP server implementations available for Windows (as Microsoft developed the protocol) and RouterOS. There is an open specification, so there isn't a reason why someone couldn't develop the server. It just hasn't been done.

Some reference links:

- [Microsoft's SSTP Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc247338.aspx)
- [SSTP Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Tunneling_Protocol)

The reasons you probably haven't seen much open-source development on this are:

- SSTP is a relatively new VPN protocol
- SSTP is a Microsoft-pushed technology
- OpenVPN already fulfills the particular needs for open-source solutions

If you want SSTP because firewalls already let through TCP port 443 traffic, OpenVPN already supports running a TCP-based server on any port, including 443. OpenVPN setups using TCP port 443 are quite common for this reason, although they're rightly not the recommended setup because running IP over TCP (especially TCP over TCP) generally gives poor performance.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/sorz/sstp-server implementation in Python\C. Limited perfomance, but works.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout [accel-ppp](https://accel-ppp.org/), its SSTP module is still beta, but I tested it a bit and it's faster than the alternatives.

Comment: Are you affiliated in any way with this project?

Comment: Nope, just a user.

Answer (score 1):

That sourceforge project is for an SSTP client, not server.  The only currently available solution for SSTP on *nix is Softether - www.softether.org

Be advised that the software is still limited - and won't run on a shared subnet of IPs.

Other than that, it really does a nice job and is fast an easy to set up, and managing it via the windows management software is a snap

Answer (score 1):

There's an option from python modules; install python on your computer and do `pip install sstp-server`.